# Populating paragraph with text from object in loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a form form that either has input/select fields in form when account status is active, in this state you are able to add/edit user info, in another state Frozen, I would use the same view but replace the input and select fields with paragraph tags `<p class="form-control-static">` for read-only purpose. I am populating the field when entering to EDIT mode with jQuery:

```
function fillFormFromObject(form, obj) {
        form.find("input, select").each(
            function (i, el) {
                console.log(el);
                $(el).val(obj[el.name]);
            }
        );
    }
```

Now in paragraph case, how can I set the text for it from the object as well? Getting lost in here. I know that for paragraph element I would call text() method. But what would I pass in?

Comment: `form.find("p").each(function (i, el) { $(el).text(obj[el.name]); });` ?

Comment: Can't do that. 'name' in this case is the name attribute of the field, for paragraph I don't have it. Currently it maps the field of the object to the field that has the same attribute 'name' as value.

Comment: What do you have for paragraph then?

Comment: Paragraph doesn't have any attributes.

Comment: Well, then how do you want to match paragraphs with object fields?

Comment: Was hoping for a different approach to somehow determine that or replace the input fields with paragraphs which would retain the value somehow.

Comment: Before writing code you should formulate algorithm in words. If you can't do it, then you won't know what to code. You can replace `<input>`s with `<p>`s, and can save `<input>`'s value as `<p>` attribute, but you should understand what exactly you want to do.

Comment: Well, the read-only requirement wasn't in scope. Was looking for a easy workaround if possible without creating separate view. Thanks anyway.

Comment: All I can suggest now is [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7yoejqry/).

Comment: Is there a reason why you are not using the disabled property on the input fields?

Comment: Well disabled property was my first choice, but someone somewhere thought having static paragraph would be better. Thanks though.

Comment: The disabled property causes a visual difference that lots of folks don't like.  but the input objects also have a readonly property.  The data can't be changed, and doesn't look different from an editable input object.

Comment: @vernonner3voltazim well, select field does not have it, can only use disabled which means separate css classes still.

Comment: For the select field you can add an `onfocus` handler.  Test a flag if you want the field to have focus, and if not, call the select object's `blur()` method to disable the focus --net effect is equivalent to readonly.

Answer (score 0):

This is a proposal for a partial Answer.  It includes some of the desired features, and doesn't include some others (which probably could be worked out with some experimenting).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>test-page</title>
 <script type="text/javascript">
//<!--

var f="i";
function inpdisp()
{ var d, i, x
  for(x=0; x<4; x++)
  { if(x<10)    //HTML code is ready for up to 100 input-fields/spans
      i="0"+x;
    else
      i=x.toString();
    d=document.getElementById("i"+i);
    d.hidden = (f=="i" ? true : false);
    // d.value="new value"+i;           //uncomment when filling data from Server
    d=document.getElementById("s"+i);
    d.hidden = (f=="i" ? false : true);
    // d.innerHTML="new value"+i+",";   //uncomment when filling data from Server
  }
  f = (f=="i" ? "s" : "i");
  return;
}

 // -->
 </script>
</head>
<body onload="inpdisp();">
<input type="button" value="inputs/displays" onclick="inpdisp();" />

 <p><input id="i00" type="text" size="20" maxlength="30" value="data00" /><span id="s00">data00,</span> &nbsp; Type of data 00</p>
 <p><input id="i01" type="text" size="20" maxlength="30" value="data01" /><span id="s01">data01,</span> &nbsp; Type of data 01</p>
 <p><input id="i02" type="text" size="20" maxlength="30" value="data02" /><span id="s02">data02,</span> &nbsp; Type of data 02</p>
 <p><input id="i03" type="text" size="20" maxlength="30" value="data03" /><span id="s03">data03,</span> &nbsp; Type of data 03</p>

</body>
</html>
```

That `inpdisp()` function is tied to a button only for "show" here.  You would eliminate the button and call the function using some other criteria, in your version of this page.  You will probably NOT want to modify the `f` variable inside the `inpdisp()` function, but do it elsewhere.